# Firebase seems to attempt to begin listening for snapshot updates before authentication sequence is run. any way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

It seems that before firebase is able to get the current user authentication data such as the email used for login, it attempts to call

```
   firestore.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email).onSnapshot(function(doc) {
      console.log("check")
   });
```

the thing is, it requires the current user's email to access the correct document in the collection from within the database.

is there any way to circumvent this and to wait until currentUser defined?

Comment: There is not enough information in you question right now to come up with a proper answer. But did you read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user) about getting the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code depends on having an authenticated user, you should run it in an `onAuthStateChanged` callback. For example:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
   firestore.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email).onSnapshot(function(doc) {
      console.log("check")
   });
  }
});
```

Also see the [Firebase documentation on getting the authenticated user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user).